# Efficient and cleaner way of assigning values

Tags: python

```
x = 5
if y > x:
    y = x
```

Seems a little archaic.

is there a more efficient way to shorten the last 2 lines here into one.

Comment: `y = min(y, x)`

Answer (score 3):

You can make those 2 lines into one:

```
if y > x: y = x
```

Or using an inline condition:

```
y = x if y > x else y
```

Or using a boolean expression *(shorter but not as easy to read)*:

```
y = [x,y][y>x]
```

Comment: are there anything wrong with using either this solution or the min, max solution below?

Comment: The `min`/`max` methods seem more of a refined way of approaching this imo.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with limits, the functions `min()` and `max()` come in handy.
**min()** returns the **smallest** item in an iterable or the smallest of two or more arguments, **max()** returns the **largest** item.

```
y = min(y, x)
```

If `y` is smaller or equal than `x`, `y` isn't changed - otherwise it is set to `x`, because `x` is the smaller value.

[Documentation: Built-in function min()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)